# C++11 number of days since date

Tags: c++, time, c++11

I need to store date in flat file. Is there any simple metod to get number of days since particular date (for example since 1 AD) using standard libary in C++11? The only one I know is to:

- obtain std::tm structure, set all time values to 0
- convert it to std::time_t (I do not know proper method yet)
- divide time_t to get the resolution of one day

Can I perform it easier?

Comment: Did you consider using the `<chrono>` standard header, new in C++11 ?

Comment: Of course. But I did not find any methods related to the topic.

Comment: If you can use `boost` I suggest you look up http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/date_time.html. The C++11 `time` category templates are usually meant for parsing and formatting and I don't think they are going to help you much.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Chrono is about timing program execution, not a general date time type.

Comment: @dirkgently I prefer to avoid boost library for a very simple reason. I had a lot of problem with boost and GCC-4.7. But I will investigate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you said sounds reasonable to start with.  You can convert the struct tm to time_t using [mktime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/mktime/).  Note that mktime interprets its input as local time according to the system/environment settings, and there is no UTC counterpart that's as widely available without relying on "extra" libraries, but maybe that's not a problem for you.